# watchkit companion app failed to start

Tags: ios, watchkit

I was debugging a watch kit extension app with notification in the device and watch. 
Then the watch app runs with the notification, and should start the companion app in the iPhone using WCSession, the iPhone prints only this in the log.
What can the problem to run the app. All settings are default offered by Xcode. The iPhone app is an old app, now I added watchkit extension. 
using watchos 2 and iOS 9.1. Min target iOS 6.0

```
iPhone SpringBoard[61] <Warning>: [FBSystemService] Error launching com.appId: Disabled (5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to remove this from the plist file.

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
    <true/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the value for `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` in your info.plist for watch kit app. It should match the bundle identifier of your application

Comment: matches the identifier. thats why iPhone com.appId print that error. Disabled (5).